# SWT - How to change the order of existing TabItems in a TabFolder

Tags: java, swt

How do I change the order of existing TabItems in a TabFolder? Sorry for not being able to post more, but I just have completely no clue. TabItems don't have a z-Index, moveAbove() and moveBelow() of the contained composites don't work, I have the feeling to have tried everything.

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On our project, we had to do that.  We disposed the old tab and created a new one on the correct position.

Comment: But, how can I create a new Tab on the "correct position"? AFAIK I can only append to the list of tabs..., or do I have to recreate the whole TabFolder?

Comment: The TabItem class has a second constructor which receives the position where it should appear.

Comment: And you can avoid recreating the tab content by re-parenting the content of the old tab to the new tabe before the old tab is disposed. So it get to be very efficient.

Comment: Correct answer. Together with reparenting the contents I was able to write a moveTab utility function. Thanks alot.